# Sending emails from CPanel email using python script

Tags: python, email, cpanel

I am trying to send emails from the Cpanel email but everything I try I face the same error
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

this is my code, I tried it with Google domain and it works fine but the Cpanel is not working ? is there a way around it to use python for sending emails ?

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
email_user = 'something@Mydomain.com'
email_password = 'password'

email_send = "someemail@gmail.com"
subject = "Testing 2"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject
h = str("Holder")
c = str("course")
t = str("trainer")
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p >Hello {h} This {t} we need your conf. on {c} </p>
  </body>
</html>
""".format(h=h , c=c , t=t) 
    
msg.attach(MIMEText(html,'html'))
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_user,email_password)
server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

So what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

**# Sending email with Cpanel by SMTP**

```
import sys
import smtplib

from_addr = 'YOUR EMAIL ADRESS'
to_addrs = ['YOUR EMAIL ADRESS']
msg = """From: Sender
To: Recipient
Subject: Okazii

The messsage here.
"""

try:
    s = smtplib.SMTP('mail.YOUR-WEBSITE.COM', 465) # put here your own SMTP PORT and hosting email  ( can be also, 26 )
    s.login('YOUR EMAIL ADRESS', 'PASSWORD')  # do not use GMAIL !!
    s.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg)
    s.quit()
except smtplib.SMTPException:
    print("Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

yes you have to change `server = smtplib.SMTP('yourDomain.com',25)`